# Why will my connected function not work when a button is clicked and lambda function does work?

Tags: pyqt, pyside6

I have been getting issues with getting a button to print when clicked. However, I am seeing weird behavior when connecting functions to the buttons.

Clicking the "Start" button does not print "Click" but clicking on "Cancel" prints "Cancel".

I am looking to see if anyone can help me determine why.

Here is my code:

```
# ctools.py

"""CTools is a GUI toolset to interact with your CTERA Environment"""

import sys

from status import run_status

from PySide2.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QMainWindow,
    QWidget,
    QGridLayout,
    QLineEdit,
    QPushButton,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QToolBar,
    QLabel,
    QHBoxLayout
)

WINDOW_WIDTH = 600
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 800
OUTPUT_HEIGHT = 200

class CToolsWindow(QMainWindow):
    """PyCalc's main window (GUI or view)."""

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("CTools 3.0")
        self.setFixedSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT)
        self.generalLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        centralWidget = QWidget(self)
        centralWidget.setLayout(self.generalLayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)
        self._createToolBar()
        self._createRunCMDDisplay()
        self._createActionButtons()
        self._createOutput()

    def _createToolBar(self):
        tools = QToolBar()
        tools.addAction("Run CMD", self.close)
        tools.addAction("Exit", self.close)
        self.addToolBar(tools)
    
    def _createRunCMDDisplay(self):
        RunCMDLayout = QGridLayout()
        requiredArgs = QLabel("<h4><b>Required Arguments:</b></h4>")
        address = QLabel("Address (Portal IP, hostname, or FQDN):")
        username = QLabel("Portal Admin Username:")
        password = QLabel("Password")
        filename = QLabel("Output Filename")
        self.addressField = QLineEdit()
        self.usernameField = QLineEdit()
        self.passwordField = QLineEdit()
        self.commandField = QLineEdit()

        RunCMDLayout.addWidget(requiredArgs, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        RunCMDLayout.addWidget(address, 1, 0)
        RunCMDLayout.addWidget(username, 1, 1)
        RunCMDLayout.addWidget(self.addressField, 2, 0)
        RunCMDLayout.addWidget(self.usernameField, 2, 1)
        RunCMDLayout.addWidget(password, 3, 0)
        RunCMDLayout.addWidget(filename, 3, 1)
        RunCMDLayout.addWidget(self.passwordField, 4, 0)
        RunCMDLayout.addWidget(self.commandField, 4, 1)

        self.generalLayout.addLayout(RunCMDLayout)

    def _createActionButtons(self):
        actionButtonLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.cancel = QPushButton("Cancel")
        self.start = QPushButton("Start")

        actionButtonLayout.addWidget(self.cancel)
        actionButtonLayout.addWidget(self.start)

        self.generalLayout.addLayout(actionButtonLayout)

    def _createOutput(self):
        self.output = QLineEdit()
        self.output.setFixedHeight(OUTPUT_HEIGHT)
        self.output.setReadOnly(True)
        self.generalLayout.addWidget(self.output)

class CTools:
    """CTools controller class"""
    def __init__(self, model, view):
        self._evaluate = model
        self._view = view
        self._connectSignalsAndSlots()

    def _on_start_button_clicked(self):
        print("Click")

    def _connectSignalsAndSlots(self):
        self._view.start.clicked.connect(self._on_start_button_clicked)
        self._view.cancel.clicked.connect(lambda: print("Cancel"))
    

def model():
    return "Hi"

def main():
    """PyCalc's main function."""
    ctoolsApp = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ctoolsWindow = CToolsWindow()
    ctoolsWindow.show()

    CTools(model=model, view=ctoolsWindow)
    
    ctoolsApp.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I noticed that moving the "_on_start_button_clicked" function into the CToolsWindow class makes the connected function work.

I had the change the call to the function to "self._view._on_start..." instead of "self._on_start...":

```
# ctools.py

"""CTools is a GUI toolset to interact with your CTERA Environment"""

import sys

from status import run_status

from PySide2.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QMainWindow,
    QWidget,
    QGridLayout,
    QLineEdit,
    QPushButton,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QToolBar,
    QLabel,
    QHBoxLayout
)

WINDOW_WIDTH = 600
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 800
OUTPUT_HEIGHT = 200

class CToolsWindow(QMainWindow):
    """PyCalc's main window (GUI or view)."""

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("CTools 3.0")
        self.setFixedSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT)
        self.generalLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        centralWidget = QWidget(self)
        centralWidget.setLayout(self.generalLayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)
        self._createToolBar()
        self._createRunCMDDisplay()
        self._createActionButtons()
        self._createOutput()

    def _createToolBar(self):
        tools = QToolBar()
        tools.addAction("Run CMD", self.close)
        tools.addAction("Exit", self.close)
        self.addToolBar(tools)
    
    def _createRunCMDDisplay(self):
        RunCMDLayout = QGridLayout()
        requiredArgs = QLabel("<h4><b>Required Arguments:</b></h4>")
        address = QLabel("Address (Portal IP, hostname, or FQDN):")
        username = QLabel("Portal Admin Username:")
        password = QLabel("Password")
        filename = QLabel("Output Filename")
        self.addressField = QLineEdit()
        self.usernameField = QLineEdit()
        self.passwordField = QLineEdit()
        self.commandField = QLineEdit()

        RunCMDLayout.addWidget(requiredArgs, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        RunCMDLayout.addWidget(address, 1, 0)
        RunCMDLayout.addWidget(username, 1, 1)
        RunCMDLayout.addWidget(self.addressField, 2, 0)
        RunCMDLayout.addWidget(self.usernameField, 2, 1)
        RunCMDLayout.addWidget(password, 3, 0)
        RunCMDLayout.addWidget(filename, 3, 1)
        RunCMDLayout.addWidget(self.passwordField, 4, 0)
        RunCMDLayout.addWidget(self.commandField, 4, 1)

        self.generalLayout.addLayout(RunCMDLayout)

    def _createActionButtons(self):
        actionButtonLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.cancel = QPushButton("Cancel")
        self.start = QPushButton("Start")

        actionButtonLayout.addWidget(self.cancel)
        actionButtonLayout.addWidget(self.start)

        self.generalLayout.addLayout(actionButtonLayout)

    def _createOutput(self):
        self.output = QLineEdit()
        self.output.setFixedHeight(OUTPUT_HEIGHT)
        self.output.setReadOnly(True)
        self.generalLayout.addWidget(self.output)

    def _on_start_button_clicked(self):
        print("Click")

class CTools:
    """CTools controller class"""
    def __init__(self, model, view):
        self._evaluate = model
        self._view = view
        self._connectSignalsAndSlots()

    def _connectSignalsAndSlots(self):
        self._view.start.clicked.connect(self._view._on_start_button_clicked)
        self._view.cancel.clicked.connect(lambda: print("Cancel"))
    

def model():
    return "Hi"

def main():
    """PyCalc's main function."""
    ctoolsApp = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ctoolsWindow = CToolsWindow()
    ctoolsWindow.show()

    CTools(model=model, view=ctoolsWindow)
    
    ctoolsApp.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You're not creating a reference to the instance, and it gets garbage collected. Change to `ctools = CTools(model=model, view=ctoolsWindow)`

Comment: Note: I'm going to assume that you're trying to follow the RealPython tutorial about the [PyQt calculator](https://realpython.com/python-pyqt-gui-calculator/). While realpython.com is normally a quite good resource of knowledge, they're human too: they're not perfect and they do mistakes as anybody (interestingly enough, even a ChatGPT answer could give a similar reply, which is a *further* reason to not blindly follow its suggestions as many unfortunately do). Their one-liner creation of the `PyCalc` instance without reference is not technically wrong, but it is for learning purposes.

Comment: It *works* because the object structure (specifically, the signal connections to instance methods) allows them to be kept alive, but creating an instance without any reference is quite dangerous if not done with deep awareness. And considering that the purpose of that code is mainly for people that don't have that level of awareness yet, that's a bad suggestion: the outcome is that when somebody without that experience and awareness tries to change that code, they get unexpected results, as you did. As a rule of thumb, *always* create references to newly created objects, even if they're local.